# Why am I losing rows when I subset?

Tags: r, subset

My data frame looks like this:

```
            Date       Time Consumption  kVARh      kW weekday
2     2016-12-13    0:15:00      90.144  0.000 360.576     Tue
3     2016-12-13    0:30:00      90.144  0.000 360.576     Tue
4     2016-12-13    0:45:00      91.584  0.000 366.336     Tue
5     2016-12-13    1:00:00      93.888  0.000 375.552     Tue
6     2016-12-13    1:15:00      88.416  0.000 353.664     Tue
7     2016-12-13    1:30:00      88.704  0.000 354.816     Tue
8     2016-12-13    1:45:00      91.296  0.000 365.184     Tue
```

I got data from a csv with date as factor, which I changed to `as.character`, and then `as.date`. Then I added a column giving me the day of week using

```
sigEx1DF$weekday <- format(as.Date(sigEx1DF$Date), "%a")
```

which I then converted to an ordered factor from Sunday through Saturday.

This is granular data from a smart meter which measures usage (consumption) at 15 minute intervals. `kW` is `Consumption*4`. I need to average each weekday and then get the max of the averages, but when I subset the data frame looks like this:

```
            Date     Time Consumption  kVARh      kW weekday
3     2016-12-13  0:30:00      90.144  0.000 360.576     Tue
8     2016-12-13  1:45:00      91.296  0.000 365.184     Tue
13    2016-12-13  3:00:00      93.600  0.000 374.400     Tue
18    2016-12-13  4:15:00      93.312  0.000 373.248     Tue
23    2016-12-13  5:30:00     107.424  0.000 429.696     Tue
28    2016-12-13  6:45:00     103.968  0.000 415.872     Tue
33    2016-12-13  8:00:00     108.576  0.000 434.304     Tue
```

Several of the 15 minute intervals are missing now (lines 4-7, for instance). I don't see a difference in rows 4-7, yet they are missing after the subset.

This is the code I used to subset:

```
bldg1_Wkdy <- subset(sort.df, weekday == c("Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri"), 
select = c("Date","Time","Consumption","kVARh","kW","weekday"))
```

Here's the data frame structure before the subset:

```
'data.frame':   72888 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Date       : Date, format: "2016-12-13" "2016-12-13" "2016-12-13" ...
 $ Time       : Factor w/ 108 levels "0:00:00","0:15:00",..: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 49 50 51 ...
 $ Consumption: num  90.1 90.1 91.6 93.9 88.4 ...
 $ kVARh      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ kW         : num  361 361 366 376 354 ...
 $ weekday    : Ord.factor w/ 7 levels "Sun"<"Mon"<"Tue"<..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
```

I go from 72888 observations to only 10,427 for the weekdays, and 10,368 for the weekends, with many rows that seem to be randomly missing as noted above. Some of the intervals have zero consumption (electricity may have been out due to storm or other reasons), but those are actually showing up in the subset data. So it doesn't seem like zeroes are causing the problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thank you, markus. Sorry about the editing. I think I have it figured out now.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `weekday == c("Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri")` you should use `weekday %in% c("Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri")`, see below a minimal test which shows how `%in%` works as expected:

```
> subset(x, weekday == c("Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri"))
   weekday
NA    <NA>
> subset(x, weekday %in% c("Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri"))
  weekday
1     Tue
```